# asp.net c# explode string to array

Tags: c#, arrays, string

I have a string in C# like this:

```
string s = "_4_5_81_9_2";
```

I want to explode it to an array like this:

```
string A[]={4,5,81,9,2}
```

with php I was doing it by explode function:

```
$A = explode("_", $s);
```

What is the similar way in C#?

Comment: that's a split in C# http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split.aspx

Comment: ya, it's better to be int A[]

Comment: Google for "how to split string in c#?" everyone jump to give an answer to my surprise yet forget this is a very low quality question which shows no effort invested in attempt to solve it. Even the Intellisense in the IDE would show you the availble Split method.

Comment: @user3797485 Please edit your question to either declare `A[]` as `int` or put strings into `{...}`. `string A[] = {4,5,81,9,2}` does not compile.

Comment: @PraveenKumar Well if this question was about c++..., but wait... are you proposing to split a string using that code?

Comment: @Steve Guess it got the wrong one... I am making the right reference. Retracted the close vote. Thanks for letting me know.

Comment: Now You make me think about it. Probably there are thousands of similar questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In c# you can use the below code

```
string[] words = s.TrimStart('_').Split('_');
```

Comment: This doesn't give the expected output

Comment: @Steve Oh, the irony :-D

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar Strange choice in every aspect indeed.

Answer (score 6):

The correct call is

```
string s = "_4_5_81_9_2";
string[] A = s.Split(new char[] { '_' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

You have an underscore at the beginning of your string to be splitted. If you want only the numbers you need to call with the StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries to avoid the initial blank string

Just to complete the answer (credit goes to @ksven being the first to spot the comment from the OP) the conversion to an array of integers takes this form

```
int[] numbers = A.Select(x => Convert.ToInt32(x)).ToArray();
```

Comment: @Steve, Ksven is right; the first parameter is an array. The overload without StringSplitOptions have the `params` modifier, but not this one

Comment: Yes yes pardon....., by the way, now its fixed answer (@Ksven) it's the best one because it transform also the string array in an integer array

Answer (score 2):

It's called `String.Split()`. You can see reference [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/b873y76a%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

```
String s = "_4_5_81_9_2" ; 
String [] result = s.Split("_".ToCharArray(), StringSplitOption.RemoveEmptyEntries) ;
```

If you want to get an array of integer :

```
 int[] result = s.Split("_".ToCharArray(), StringSplitOption.RemoveEmptyEntries).Select(c => Convert.ToInt32(c)).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
string s = "_4_5_81_9_2";
String[] items = s.Split(new char[] { '_' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

This removes empty entries resulting from the starting `_` or a double underscore.

Answer (score 0):

```
                        string s = "_4_5_81_9_2";

                        if(s.StartsWith("_")){
                           s = s.Substring(1).Replace('_', ',');
                        }

                        string [] s2 = s.Split(',').ToArray();
                        
                        //or simply...
                        string[] s3 = s.TrimStart('_').Split('_');
                        



                        MessageBox.Show(" s2: " + s2.GetValue(0) + "" + " s: " + s.ToString()+" s3:"+s3.GetValue(0));
```